# Modulo hashing scheme

Tags: hash

Let's consider hashing of odd 256-bit number $L$ with 256-bit odd key $K$:

$z = (2^{256}-L) \cdot K \bmod 2^{256}$

$z$ is the hashed number.

1. If $K$ is selected randomly is it secure to hashing numbers this way? It is as far as I know just linear congruential generator, they are not secure. But this is slightly different (we have exponentiation in modulus and we are not using it to generate some sequence of numbers, we have no seed, just numbers to hash). Why exactly it can't be secure?
2. Is it secure if $L$ and $K$ are selected randomly, to hash $L$ this way?

Comment: Hash functions hash arbitrary length inputs, where you limit the input the same as output. Also, you might call this keyed-hash function, rather than just a hash function.

Comment: The exponentiation in the modulus is misleading you. It is just a number as the $m$ in the LCG. Also, $2^{256}-L$ has no effect on the security. On can simply consider $z = (L) \cdot K$. Now hint: one can easily find collisions, due to the multiplication and mod.

Comment: What you mean by "if L and K are selected randomly"? L is a message that you hash. Word "randomly" is not applicable to it. Message cannot be selected. Message is what is given.

Comment: And what you mean by "we have exponentiation in modulus"? $2{256}$ is just compact representation. You can write it also without exponent: 100000....00000 (one 1 and 256 zeroes).

Comment: Kelalaka - there are no collisions in this mapping. Every odd $L$ gives unique $z$ with every key. Mentallurg - randomly means like in OWF function, with fixed $K$ it could be hard to invert randomly selected $L$, then it is not a messege, just random input. And exponentiation is kind of my mistake, kelalaka is right, it is just $2^{256}$, ordinary number.

Comment: But $K$ are odd and inputs $L$ are also odd so they will be always relatively prime to modulus. Or I'm still don't understand something?

Comment: Oh, missed that. Then you actually have 255 bits message space and 255 bits keyspace.  This turns your scheme into encryption, Affine cipher.

Comment: And why modulus has to be prime? About Lehmer random number generator wikipedia wrote - using a modulus m which is a power of two makes for a particularly convenient computer implementation, but comes at a cost: the period is at most m/4, and the low bits have periods shorter than that. But we don't care about period. We would like to compute only one iteration. So we are in (secure?) period.

Comment: If prime than you don't have restrictions on the key and the message. You may not in the period, however, how will one be going to hash 256-bit file? Your function doesn't satisfy the basic definition of a hash function. When you start to hash more than 255 bits, one can talk about the collisions. You merely have cipher there.

Comment: Yes, it was intended to be a cipher. By the way wikipedia wrote more about Lehmer random number generator with $2^{n}$ mod. They wrote - the application using these random numbers must use the most significant bits; reducing to a smaller range using a modulo operation with an even modulus will produce disastrous results. So it looks like we can encrypt this way, but it has to be mapping which transform every 256-bit input into let's say 64 output (maybe less) of most significant bits (we have to cut all the other bits). Then it is not so obvious to find a collisions, but they will occure.